# what's the scope of a mule message?

Tags: mule

In trying to restore the original payload in a message, I ran into this issue that confused me regarding the scope of a mule message. Given the mule config below, I initially assumed that the payload received at the `test.Name` vm endpoint was going to be restored at the end of the flow (see 1. and 2. in the config):

```
<mule  ...>     
    <vm:endpoint name="replacePayloadWithFoo.Name"
            path="replacePayloadWithFoo.Path" />

    <flow name="test">
        <vm:inbound-endpoint name="test.Name" path="test.Path"
            exchange-pattern="request-response" />

        <!-- 1. Down below, I wanted to restore the payload at this point -->

        <expression-transformer evaluator="string"
            expression="bar" />

        <outbound-endpoint ref="replacePayloadWithFoo.Name"
            exchange-pattern="request-response" />

        <!-- 2. The transformer below does not restore the payload at 1. -->            

        <expression-transformer evaluator="groovy"
                expression="message.originalPayload" />
    </flow>

    <flow name="replacePayloadWithFoo">
        <inbound-endpoint ref="replacePayloadWithFoo.Name"
            exchange-pattern="request-response" />

        <expression-transformer evaluator="string"
            expression="foo" />

    </flow>

</mule>
```

However, it seemed as though the  message that entered the `test` flow ended at the `replacePayloadWithFoo` outbound endpoint. The transformer at 2. leaves `"foo"` as the payload.

What's the scope of the mule message?

In passing, the [scripting reference documentation](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Scripting+Module+Reference) indicates that there is a binding for `originalPayload` in groovy scripts. However, if the transformer at 2. is replaced with

```
<expression-transformer evaluator="groovy" expression="originalPayload" />
```

I get an exception:

```
org.mule.api.expression.RequiredValueException: Expression Evaluator "groovy"
with expression "originalPayload" returned null but a value was required.
```

What could be the issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any outbound interaction, unless performed through an enricher, will affect the current in-flight message. This is why the call to replacePayloadWithFoo replaces the original message with the result of the outbound interaction.

This said, I can not explain the discrepancy between:

```
<expression-transformer evaluator="groovy" expression="message.originalPayload" />
```

and:

```
<expression-transformer evaluator="groovy" expression="originalPayload" />
```

because they both rely on:

```
event.getMessage().getPayload()
```

Comment: Many thanks! You rock! could you point to a documentation page that elaborates on the topic of the message scope? Regarding the issue with originalPayload, would you like me to post an example to help reproduce it?

Comment: I can't think of any doc page re:message scope :( And yes please open a new issue for this discrepancy between `message.originalPayload` and `originalPayload`, it's worth a deeper look.